# Automatic date calculation in MS Word (maybe using macro)?

Tags: microsoft-word, macros

I want to have a Date field (manually entered or automatically display "today's date") and a second Date field, such as Due Date and Due Time. I want the Due Date/Time to be automatically calculated from Today's Date.
Would it be done in field codes or macros, which is easier?
Will need to be able modify the code for the difference in dates and times.

Answer (score 1):

Word is not made for such calculations.

You may insert easily enough a date field having today as its default value,
as described in the Microsoft article
[Insert today's date in a Word document](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-today-s-date-in-a-word-document-fe7c08fe-7192-44a5-ac0a-88ccd51532ab).

For calculating a field whose value is 14 days in the future,
you will need this monstrosity:

```
{QUOTE "{SET Delay "14"}{SET "DaysInMonth" {IF {DATE \@ "MM"}
<> 2 {=ROUND(30.575*{DATE \@ "MM"},0)-ROUND(30.575*{= {DATE \@
"MM"} –1},0)}{IF {=MOD({DATE \@ "yy"|, 4)} > 0 "28" "29"}}}{SET
"NextMonth" {IF {DATE \@ "MM"} = 12 "1/97" "{= {DATE \@ "MM"}
+ 1}/97}}{IF {= {REF Delay} + {DATE \@ "dd"}} <= {DaysInMonth}
{DATE \@ "MMMM {= {REF Delay} + {DATE \@ "dd"}}, yyyy"}{QUOTE
"{NextMonth \@ "MMMM"} {= {REF Delay} + {DATE \@ "dd"} –
{DaysInMonth}}, {IF {DATE \@ "MM"} <> 12 {DATE \@ "yyyy"}{DATE
\@ "{= 1 + {DATE \@ "yyyy"} \# "xxxx"}" }}}}"}
```

Source:
[Calculating Dates with Fields](http://www.addbalance.com/word/datefields2.htm).